# activating and deactivating user in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, phpmyadmin

[image]

[image]

i'm having trouble with my Activate/Deactivate button. when i press Deactivate button it would shift to "Inactive" status and updates my database. but when i Press the Activate button nothing happens. And i tried so many things but i cant find what is wrong with my codes. Hope someone will hear me out. Thank you!

```
    protected void BindGridView()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("Select id,username,user_type,first_name,last_name,email,address,contact_number,status FROM user_tbl", con);

        con.Open();
        da.Fill(dt);
        con.Close();

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }


    protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
    {
        // id of edit row
        string id = GridView1.DataKeys[e.NewSelectedIndex].Value.ToString();
        string status = GridView1.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex].Cells[7].Text;
        int newstat = 0;
        if (status == "Active")
        {
            status = "Inactive";
            newstat = 0;
        }
        if (status == "Inactive")
        {
            status = "Active";
            newstat = 1;
        }
        // update record
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("update user_tbl set status='" + newstat + "'where ID=" + id, con);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        BindGridView();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `SelectedIndexChanging` not fire second time if your click twice same button. Try to put your code from  `SelectedIndexChanging` into `OnClick="EventHandler"`.

```
<asp:Button OnClick="myButtonClick" />

void myButtonClick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      ...
}
```